# How to configure ldap one slave - mutlimaster replication

Tags: replication, openldap

I just successfully replicated Openldap using ubuntu 10.04 as master (provider), 12.04 as slave (consumer).

I'm using syncrepl method for this replication.

Below configuration for provider.ldif and consumer.ldif

```
### provider ###
# Add indexes to the frontend db.
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcDbIndex
olcDbIndex: entryCSN eq
-
add: olcDbIndex
olcDbIndex: entryUUID eq

#Load the syncprov and accesslog modules.
dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: syncprov
-
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: accesslog

# Accesslog database definitions
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcHdbConfig
olcDatabase: {2}hdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap/accesslog
olcSuffix: cn=accesslog
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=teleneos,dc=org
olcDbIndex: default eq
olcDbIndex: entryCSN,objectClass,reqEnd,reqResult,reqStart

# Accesslog db syncprov.
dn: olcOverlay=syncprov,olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: add
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcSyncProvConfig
olcOverlay: syncprov
olcSpNoPresent: TRUE
olcSpReloadHint: TRUE

# syncrepl Provider for primary db
dn: olcOverlay=syncprov,olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
changetype: add
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcSyncProvConfig
olcOverlay: syncprov
olcSpNoPresent: TRUE

# accesslog overlay definitions for primary db
dn: olcOverlay=accesslog,olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcAccessLogConfig
olcOverlay: accesslog
olcAccessLogDB: cn=accesslog
olcAccessLogOps: writes
olcAccessLogSuccess: TRUE
# scan the accesslog DB every day, and purge entries older than 7 days
olcAccessLogPurge: 07+00:00 01+00:00
```

Then below consumer.ldif

```
### consumer ###
#Load the syncprov module.
dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: syncprov

# syncrepl specific indices
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcDbIndex
olcDbIndex: entryUUID eq
-
add: olcSyncRepl
olcSyncRepl: rid=0 provider=ldap://192.168.2.29 bindmethod=simple binddn="cn=admin,dc=teleneos,dc=org" 
 credentials=teleneos searchbase="dc=teleneos,dc=org" logbase="cn=accesslog" 
 logfilter="(&(objectClass=auditWriteObject)(reqResult=0))" schemachecking=on 
 type=refreshAndPersist retry="60 +" syncdata=accesslog
-
add: olcUpdateRef
olcUpdateRef: ldap://192.168.2.29
```

This is succesfully replicated, when i add value on provider, then will replicated on consumer (slave). But this is only 2 machine connected.How if i have more than 10 machine as provider(master).Should on customer.ldif add olcUpdateRef: ldap://url_ldap one by one ?

```
 add: olcUpdateRef
olcUpdateRef: ldap://192.168.2.29
olcUpdateRef: ldap://192.168.2.30
olcUpdateRef: ldap://192.168.2.31
...
...

olcUpdateRef: ldap://192.168.2.39
```

Any another configuration for this case ? i think if i add one by one url of ldap master i will not effective.

Help me to solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me that this is a supported configuration or that it will work, but if so all you should need is multiple `syncrepl` directives in the consumer.

NB you shouldn't load the `syncprov` module in the consumer.

Comment: But, is my schema possible ? any sample configuration or reference for that ?